$\sum_{n=R}^{\infty}{\binom{n}{R}\frac{a^n}{(1+a)^{n+1}}} = a^R$
for any $R \in \mathbb{N}$ I want to show the identity
$$\sum_{n=R}^{\infty}{\binom{n}{R}\frac{a^n}{(1+a)^{n+1}}} = a^R$$
I had an argument that I really liked but unfortunately it has some mistakes, nevertheless I post it here hoping someone will find a way to fix the argument.
Let $$f(a) := \sum_{n=R}^{\infty}{\binom{n}{R}\frac{a^n}{(1+a)^{n+1}}}$$
near $a = 0$ I have
$$f(a) = a^R + a^{R+1} \cdot (p(a))$$
where $p(a)$ is an analytic function.
Now here is the first mistake, which is that a I can't say that this identity still holds for large $|a|$. Let's assume it still does.
At this point I just have to show that $|f(a)| \lesssim a^{R}$, as this implies $p = 0$

whenever $A(a)$ and $B(a)$ are two functions, by $A \lesssim B$ I mean that there exists a large $C > 0$ and radius $\rho > 0$ such that whenever $|a|> \rho$ one has $|A(a)| \leq C |B(a)|$

Now the second mistake, I have to assume $a$ very big and that I can find some $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\alpha \approx 1+a$, which I can't do since $a \in \mathbb{C}$, so assume $a >> 0$.
Now I can take $\alpha := \lfloor 1+a \rfloor$ and by the change of variable $n = m\alpha + q$, and observing that $\binom{n}{R} \leq n^R$ and $(1-\frac{1}{a+1})^\alpha \approx 1/e$
$$ f(a) \leq \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{q=1}^{\alpha}{\frac{1}{\alpha}(m\alpha + q)^R(1-\frac{1}{1+a})^{m\alpha+q}}} \leq \alpha^{R-1} \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{\sum_{q=1}^{\alpha}{(m+1)^R(1-\frac{1}{1+a})^{m\alpha}}} \lesssim \alpha^{R}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{(m+1)^Re^{-m}} \lesssim \alpha^{R} \leq a^{R}$$
So this should complete the proof.
Do you think I can fix the two mistakes? if so, how? I just like the argument and I would like to find a way to make it work

I am not sure if your argument is correct, but an alternate approach would be to consider the function $g(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$ for $|x|<1$ and then differentiate it $R$ times to obtain $$g^{(R)}(x) = \frac{R!}{(1-x)^{R+1}} = \sum_{n=R}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-R)!}x^{n-R}.$$ Plugging in $x=\frac{a}{a+1}$ for $-\frac{1}{2}<a<\infty$ gives the required result.

Nice! Also, thanks to the identity principles this shows the equality for all $a$ such that $\Re(a) > -1$

The identity doesn't hold for $a\le -\frac{1}{2}$ as in that case $x\le -1$. @Paul

I know but it doesn't matter, you just showed that, given $f(a) := \sum_{n=R}^{\infty}{\binom{n}{R}\frac{a^n}{(1+a)^{n+1}}} - a^R$, one has $f(a) = 0$ for all $a > 1/2$. Now $f$ is an holomorphic function on the connected domain ${ \Re(a) > -1}$, so by the Identity principle $f$ is always $0$

The series in the definition of $f$ does not converge for $|a|\ge |1+a|$ which is equivalent to $\mathcal{R}(a)\le 1/2.$ So it does not define any function in that area.

@RyszardSzwarc oh you're right, my bad

$$\sum_{n=R}^{\infty}{\binom{n}{R}\frac{a^n}{(1+a)^{n+1}}}=\frac 1{a+1}\sum_{n=R}^{\infty}  {\binom{n}{R}}x^n \qquad \text{with} \qquad x=\frac a{1+a}$$
$$\sum_{n=R}^{\infty}  {\binom{n}{R}}x^n= \frac { x^R}{(1-x)^{R+1} }$$ Replace $x$ by its definition.

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align*}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{n = R}^{\infty}{n \choose R}{a^{n} \over \pars{1 + a}^{n + 1}}} =
\sum_{n = R}^{\infty}{n \choose n - R}{a^{n} \over \pars{1 + a}^{n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\sum_{n = R}^{\infty}{-R - 1 \choose n - R}
\pars{-1}^{n - R}\,\,{a^{n} \over \pars{1 + a}^{n + 1}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-R - 1 \choose n}\pars{-1}^{n}
{a^{n + R} \over \pars{1 + a}^{n + R + 1}}
\\[5mm] = & \
{a^{R} \over \pars{1 + a}^{R + 1}}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{-R - 1 \choose n}\pars{-\,{a \over 1 + a}}^{n}
\\[5mm] = & \
{a^{R} \over \pars{1 + a}^{R + 1}}
\pars{1 - {a \over a + 1}}^{-R - 1} =
{a^{R} \over \pars{1 + a}^{R + 1}}
{1 \over \pars{a + 1}^{-R - 1}}
\\[5mm] = & \ \bbx{\color{#44f}{a^{R}}}
\end{align*}
